# Am I forced to use Power BI Desktop to provide datasets to Power BI Service other than local or sharepoint files?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'v been assigned the task to research Power BI Service platform to see if it is useful for the company I'm working at. I have a Power BI Pro license and basically my goal is to create several reports and dashboards from disparate data sources such as REST APIs, mongodb, SQL Server, csv and excel files.

I would like to create the mentioned datasets directly from the Power BI service website but I see that I only can create datasets from csv or excel files. And if I select SQL Server, it asks me to download Power BI Desktop client. The other type of data sources that I need are not even mentioned.

My question is if Power BI Desktop is required to develop and configure datasets for the Power BI service, because to begin with it is a windows only application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are. The desktop version provides the full power of the software. You can learn a TON of things from [this guy on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRNmSv7mAPYiC0Y40TJijAw) and also from [these guys in a cube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFp1vaKzpfvoGai0vE5VJ0w). I'm willing to bet you can search the questions you have & can find specific example videos that'll help you determine if this software is right your company. In my opinion, when it comes to **data visualization software**, it's tough to beat `Power BI`. That's especially true if your company is on **Office 365**.

As a tip, it's important to note what kind of data sources you need to communicate with. And are those sources in a cloud or on premise. That's important depending on how "live" you want your data to be.

Comment: Just found the guy in a cube. Nice tips!

Comment: @DanielSan, yes sir, those guys live for PBI. True pro's. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The main use of Power BI Desktop (Windows only application) is to get the data from the sources into data model, then load it to the service. The data connections and the ability to create reports is limited compared to the service. The main goal of the service is to share the reports and collaboration.
For example there is no realtionship designer in the service to connect the imported entities. You can create a report in the desktop and load it to the service, and then create other reports from its dataset in the service.

You can create dataflows in the service to get data from flat files, and databases, but you then use Desktop to connect to them and link them together there.